# Jeditable and AJAX reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jeditable

I have a table that i load with AJAX and edit with Jeditable.
This is how i start my function:

```
function refresh_page() {
var tableElm = $('#refresh');
$.ajax({
    url: 'assets/php/ritsys/my_table.php',
    success: function(data) {
        if (!($("*:focus").is("textarea, input, select, date, time")) ) {
            tableElm.html(data)
        }
        $(function(){
            $('.edit').editable('assets/php/ritsys/save.php', {
                indicator : '<img src="assets/css/smoothness/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif">'
            });
        });
        setTimeout(refresh_page, 1500);
    }
}); };
```

This works fine and i added the **if (!($("*:focus").is("textarea, input, select, date, time")) ) {** line because i had problems with the data refreshing while i was editing something in the table.

But after i added this everytime when i update a value in the table firstly it shows me the indicator image, then the old value and after that the new value.

Before it would briefly show the indicator and then the new value. Can somebody help me to cut out the step where it shows the old data?

It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the script *assets/php/ritsys/save.php* return the "new" value? You should return the "new" value, not the "old" value. The returned value will be shown when the request is complete.